# how to update a column based on another column using case when?

Tags: postgresql

I have this table:

client

```
id   |  name       | surname
----------------------------
1    | 'walid'     | null
2    | 'wahid'     | null
3    | 'kais'      | null
4    | 'wadii'     | null
5    | 'walla'     | null
6    | 'anis'      | null
7    | 'chawki'    | null
8    | 'boubaker'  | null
9    | 'noureddine'| null
```

i need to get this table

```
id   |  name     | surname
----------------------------
1    | walid ha  | saadli
2    | wahid ha  | saadli
3    | kais      | saadli
4    | wadii     | saadli
5    | walla     | rebhi
6    | walla ay  | rebhi
7    | chawki    | akrout
8    | boubaker  | akrout
9    | noureddine| akrout
10   | walid hous| saadli
```

I want to search the list of words when name = ['.*walid.*','.*wahid.*','.*kais.*','.*wadii.*'] and set their surname= 'saadli', else when name = ['.*walaa.*'] then surname = 'rebhi' else when name = ['.*chawki.*','.*boubaker.*', '.*noureddine.*'] then surname = 'akrout'

i created this query:

```
with clnt as (
    select * from client )
select name from clnt

update client
set surname = case 
    when REGEXP_MATCHES(name, '.*walid.*|.*wahid.*|.*kais.*|.*wadii.*', 'g') then 'saadli'
    when REGEXP_MATCHES(name, '.*walaa.*','g') then 'rebhi'
    when REGEXP_MATCHES(name, '.*chawki.*|.*boubaker.*|.*noureddine.*') then 'akrout' END
FROM clnt
```

i got an error:

[image]

Comment: You don't need any of that `WITH` or `FROM clnt`. An `UPDATE` query can already refer to any columns of the table it is updating.

Comment: `regexp_matches` returns an array of the matches. You want the `~`  operator that returns `true` or `false` _if_ the pattern matches.

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your statement. The CTE is completely unnecessary but is the reason for the "ambiguous" column error, so removing that gets rid of that problem.

But more importantly, `regexp_matches()` does not return a boolean value that is required by the CASE expressions, but an array of all matches. You probably want to use the `~` operator instead:

```
update client
set surname = case 
               when name ~ '.*walid.*|.*wahid.*|.*kais.*|.*wadii.*' then 'saadli'
               when name ~ '.*walaa.*' then 'rebhi'
               when name ~ '.*chawki.*|.*boubaker.*|.*noureddine.*' then 'akrout' 
             END
where surname is null; --<< don't overwrite existing values
```

Comment: i got the next error :

    "ERROR:  relation "data" does not exist
    CONTEXT:  SQL statement "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW data"
    PL/pgSQL function data_dup() line 3 at SQL statement
    SQL state: 42P01"


i have no MATERIALIZED VIEW  implemented

Comment: @ghilani: then you might have a trigger n the table `client` - but that is a completely different question.